# Convert daily data into the weekly format in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

```
Conversiondate         Activity
2013-09-30 00:00:00    Renaissance_Homepage_022013
2013-09-12 00:00:00    RFP - Total
2013-09-23 00:00:00    Reservations Rate List Menu
2013-09-08 00:00:00    SHS 2.0 Home
2013-09-17 00:00:00    MR Promo Registration Confirmation
2013-09-13 00:00:00    Renaissance_ReservationOverlay_022013
2013-09-02 00:00:00    Reservations Rate List Menu
2013-09-13 00:00:00    Renaissance_HotelPage_022013
2013-09-08 00:00:00    Reservations Rate List Menu
```

I have above table consist of date and activity. Now I want write the script where i can find new activity each week. for example: I have 10 activity in current week and there will another 2 activity will add in next week. So, those 2 will be new and want to write the script to find that new activity in below format on weekly base;

The week will start from Sunday.

```
StartDateWEEk     ENDDATEWEEK             Activity          Week
----------------------------------------------------------------    
2013-09-01         2013-09-07         Booking Confo          36
2013-09-01         2013-09-07         Mobile                 36
2013-09-08         2013-09-14         Mobileconfo            37
2013-09-08         2013-09-14         Mobile                 37
2013-09-08         2013-09-14         Reservation            37
```

I want to create this format and you can see that on 37th week there is one new activity came call **reservation**. I want to set up automate process to catch those new activity each week.

Comment: How did you get these `Activity` Values in your desired output ??

Comment: @M.Ali: There is only one table from where i have to find new activity  each week.

Answer (score 1):

I am only guessing on how you got the activity column in your Desired OUPUT anyway this is something I would do....

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE( Conversiondate DATETIME,Activity VARCHAR(400))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('2013-09-30 00:00:00','Renaissance_Homepage_022013'),
('2013-09-12 00:00:00','RFP - Total'),
('2013-09-23 00:00:00','Reservations Rate List Menu'),
('2013-09-08 00:00:00','SHS 2.0 Home'),
('2013-09-17 00:00:00','MR Promo Registration Confirmation'),
('2013-09-13 00:00:00','Renaissance_ReservationOverlay_022013'),
('2013-09-02 00:00:00','Reservations Rate List Menu'),
('2013-09-13 00:00:00','Renaissance_HotelPage_022013'),
('2013-09-08 00:00:00','Reservations Rate List Menu')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT   CAST(DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, Conversiondate)-1)
                         , Conversiondate) AS DATE) [WeekStart]
        ,CAST(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, Conversiondate))
                          , Conversiondate) AS DATE) [WeekEnd]
        ,  Activity
        ,DATEPART(WEEK, Conversiondate) [Week_Number]
FROM @TABLE
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ WeekStart  ║  WeekEnd   ║               Activity                ║ Week_Number ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 2013-09-29 ║ 2013-10-05 ║ Renaissance_Homepage_022013           ║          40 ║
║ 2013-09-08 ║ 2013-09-14 ║ RFP - Total                           ║          37 ║
║ 2013-09-22 ║ 2013-09-28 ║ Reservations Rate List Menu           ║          39 ║
║ 2013-09-08 ║ 2013-09-14 ║ SHS 2.0 Home                          ║          37 ║
║ 2013-09-15 ║ 2013-09-21 ║ MR Promo Registration Confirmation    ║          38 ║
║ 2013-09-08 ║ 2013-09-14 ║ Renaissance_ReservationOverlay_022013 ║          37 ║
║ 2013-09-01 ║ 2013-09-07 ║ Reservations Rate List Menu           ║          36 ║
║ 2013-09-08 ║ 2013-09-14 ║ Renaissance_HotelPage_022013          ║          37 ║
║ 2013-09-08 ║ 2013-09-14 ║ Reservations Rate List Menu           ║          37 ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ali for your help and it's work really good. Now I want to do something whereas i can set up automate SQL process and  i Can find new activity each week. For example: there are 10 activity names in first week and 13 in second week that mean 3 new activity in second week. So,  how can i find that new activity each week? I want to set up this process forever from January 2013 to Dec 2020. This is new to me so I am really confused about this requirements.

Comment: Thanks Ali , this works good however if i want to set up this script in automate mode for 2013 to 2020 then how can be this possible?

Comment: In sql server Time bound execution is handled in two ways. 1) using sql server agent jobs 2) using WAITFOR claue in your code.  In your case you will a sql server agent job will be more suitable choice. [`Read here`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153(v=sql.105).aspx) to learn more about sql server agent jobs. Also if the answer helped you please accept it :) good luck

Comment: ok thanks for answer and I know about Agent job very well. but can you please tell me how would i know that new activity come in table through that automate process. If i want to know 2 new activity come in next week then which new activity came how would i know that?...

Comment: I am trying to accept your answer but they are saying you should have at least 15 reputation for that.

Comment: Like I said before time bound code executions are handled with two option that I have mentioned before now you are asking about event bound executions, event(Insert/Delete/Update) bound code executions are handled by triggers, In your case you will need an `After Insert Trigger` [`Read here`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to learn more about triggers.